# PHP: count amount of tabs at the beginning of a string

Tags: php, count

Ok basically I have a string which could be anything but for the purposes of the question it is:

```
    Hello World
```

As you can see it has been indented twice at the beginning and once at the end.
Is there a way to count the amount of tabs `\t` only at the beginning of the string with PHP?

Cheers Franky

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this code, it does exactly what you ask:

```
strspn($string, "\t");
```

http://www.php.net/strspn

Comment: I believe that would return 2 for something like `"x\t\t"`. In that case you'd actually need `strspn("\t$string", "\t")-1`.

Comment: Nah, I suppose you are thinking of strcspn(), counting the first characters of subject that are NOT in mask, which is the opposite of strspn does and what was asked.

Comment: Im in agreement with @Jacob, I have never come across this function. Never the less I shall try it out.

Comment: Many functions like this one came from the C world. That is why they have these telegraphic names that only C programmers know. :-)

Comment: @mlemos, you are right. I was thinking of a time I used them with the offset parameters.